# Class name class variable = null - what does this line mean in Android?

Tags: android-studio

I am having trouble understanding the meaning of the following code:

```
public class CustomListViewAndroidExample extends Activity {                                  
    ListView list;                                                                            
    CustomAdapter adapter;                                                                    
    public CustomListViewAndroidExample CustomListView = null;   // What does this line mean?

    public ArrayList<ListModel> CustomListViewValuesArr = new ArrayList<ListModel>();
```

Comment: Its instance of current activity you can use like CustomListView .addContentView

Answer (score 1):

Its instance of current activity you can use in oncreate like

```
CustomListView.addContentView(view, params);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just like an "ordinary" variable except that it's explicitly set to `null` when the class is created. It's no different in principal than the following line:

```
CustomListViewValuesArr = new ArrayList<ListModel>();
```

This isn't really any different than setting the value in the constructor or OnCreate method.

Note that, as with your other variables, you'll need to initialize this to something other than `null` in order to be able to use it.

It is slightly odd that it's `public`, though. I'd also recommend including explicit access modifiers in front of your other fields - it's a bad practice to omit them and rely on the defaults.